# How do I get solr term frequency?

Tags: lucene, solr, lucene.net, solrnet

I have a question that how could somebody get term frequency as we do get in lucene by the following method
DocFreq(new Term("Field", "value")); using solr/solrnet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try [debugQuery=on](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrRelevancyFAQ#Why_does_id%3aarchangel_come_before_id%3ahawkgirl_when_querying_for_.22wings.22) or [TermsComponent](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/TermsComponent). None of them are currently supported through SolrNet, so you can either work around it, or implement them and contribute them to the project.

Comment: +1 for the contributor appeal. Actually i will have a look inside your SolrNet (http://code.google.com/p/solrnet/)  project.