# counting the word frequency in lucene index

Tags: search, lucene, word-frequency

Can someone help me finding the word frequency in all lucene index
for example if doc A has 3 number of word (B) and doc C has 2 of them, I'd like a method to return 5 showing the frequency of word (B) in all lucene index

Comment: what kind of an index size are you looking at? depending on that you might want to think of using Hadoop to do so, or a simple index parser to collect the word frequencies in a map.

Answer (score 9):

This has been asked multiple times:

- [Get term frequencies in Lucene](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/667389/get-term-frequencies-in-lucene)
- [How to count term frequency for set of documents?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2924089/how-to-count-term-frequency-for-set-of-documents)
- [Get highest frequency terms from Lucene index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2821903/get-highest-frequency-terms-from-lucene-index)
- [How do I get solr term frequency?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3905101/how-do-i-get-solr-term-frequency)

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you work with Lucene 3.x:

```
IndexReader ir = IndexReader.open(dir); 
TermDocs termDocs = ir.termDocs(new Term("your_field", "your_word"));
int count = 0;
while (termDocs.next()) {
   count += termDocs.freq();
}
```

**Some comments:**

`dir` is the instance of Lucene [Directory class](http://lucene.apache.org/java/3_0_0/api/core/org/apache/lucene/store/Directory.html). It's creation differs for RAM and Filesystem indexes, see Lucene documentation for details.

`"your_filed"` is a filed to search a term. If you have multiple fields, you can run procedure for all of them or, alternatively, when you index your files, you can create special field (e.g. "_content") and keep there concatenated values of all other fields.

Comment: awfully `TermDocs` is not in lucene 5.3.1 which I use :(

Answer (score 1):

## using lucene 3.4

easy way to get the count, but you need two arrays :-/

```
int[] docs = new int[1000];
int[] freqs = new int[1000];
int count = indexReader.termDocs(term).read(docs, freqs);
```

beware: if you would use for read you are not able to use next() any more, because after the read() you are already at the end of the enumeration:

```
int[] docs = new int[1000];
int[] freqs = new int[1000];
TermDocs td = indexReader.termDocs(term);
int count = td.read(docs, freqs);
while (td.next()){ // always false, already at the end of the enumartion
}
```