# Lucene index: Terms counts

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6, lucene

I need to create a tag cloud based on certain tag/keyword which indexed by lucene .
I noticed that, Luke (a toolbox to peek into lucene index) has the features of counting the term frequecy/count.

1. is the current ADC in sitecore able to retrieve the term frequency?
2. if not, can i directly access to the index files? If so, what is the format for the index file?

It is possible for me to manually calculate the term frequency, but the performance will be very terrible as I got millions of records.

Comment: I think that what you are asking has already been answered in this [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4167735/counting-the-word-frequency-in-lucene-index)

Comment: @user2035730, if that's the case, consider deleting your question as it adds no value in its current form

Answer (score 0):

If you're on sitecore 7, you can use the facet logic for this. Use one field to store the wordt that should appear in the cloud.
Do a facet on that field and use the count of each facet-item to determine the size of the item.